# Generating objects in python 3.4.3

Tags: python, class, object, iteration

So I have had to try and generate objects during the runtime of my code before now, and have failed every time. As a very simple example, I want the commented stuff to happen when I run the program, so that it generates objects of the class foo:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, name, amount, bool):
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        self.bool = bool

desired_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

for x in desired_names:
    #Create objected assigned to the item in list, and give
    #all the objects an amount of 100 and a bool of True
    #This shoudl create:

    #name1  = foo('name1', 100, True)
    #name2  = foo('name2', 100, True)
    #name3  = foo('name3', 100, True)
```

I have looked around and not found anything useful that I can understand. I would also like to not have to just write the objects to a new file and then import the new file as I have been doing before now. HOWEVER if this is the only way to do this, please let me know! :)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks a bunch!!!!!

Comment: "I would also like to also not like to have to just write the objects to a new file." Sorry, can you rephrase that? Like to not like...?

Comment: @Kevin Sorry, I was in a big rush when I wrote this and needed to get it written down before I forgot my problem, It has been corrected now. Is that any better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comp to store the objects:

```
desired_names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
objs = [foo(name,100, True) for name in desired_names]
```

Or a dict to access by name:

```
d = {name:foo(name,100, True) for name in desired_names}
```

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور, I would not worry about it, it happens!

Answer (score 3):

You can make a list of the objects you want to create :

```
object_list = []

for x in desired_names: 
     object_list.append(foo(x,100,True))

print object_list
```

you would also have to define a `__str__` method in your class to print it the way you want